# Is there a way to check if 2 UIButtons were clicked?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 groups of `UIButtons` with Pass or Fail. I need to check if in both groups was clicked any of the UIButtons (Pass or Fail) to scroll down to next question.

I'm using a delegate with 4 parameters (my 4 buttons) and I'm doing a `if` check, but is never entering in my `if` condition. Here's how my group of buttons looks:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
func tappedOnVehicleOrTrailerButtons(vehiclePassBtn: UIButton, vehicleFailBtn: UIButton, trailerPassBtn: UIButton, trailerFailBtn: UIButton) {

    if (vehiclePassBtn.isTouchInside || vehicleFailBtn.isTouchInside) && (trailerPassBtn.isTouchInside || trailerFailBtn.isTouchInside) {

        scrollDown()
    }
}
```

Here is the delegate method:

```
// Check if the user press Pass or Fail btn for Vehicle or Trailer

@IBAction func passOrFailBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
          delegate?.tappedOnVehicleOrTrailerButtons(vehiclePassBtn: vehiclePassButton, vehicleFailBtn: vehicleFailButton, trailerPassBtn: trailerPassButton, trailerFailBtn: trailerFailButton)
}
```

Is any other way to do it instead of `if` statement?

Comment: Make sure that you have a reference for each button. Then, use the `isSelected` state for differentiating between checked/unchecked (you _must_ implement custom logic - there is no default behavior àla `UISwitch`) and then just implement whatever validation logic based on that. No need for delegation or multi-argument functions. I hope that this makes sense...

Comment: when do you call this tappedOnVehicleOrTrailerButtons method?

Comment: All 4 buttons are connected to the same IBAction function where I call the delegate.

Comment: Before calling the delegate assign sender.isSelected = true and check vehiclePassBtn.isSelected in tappedOnVehicleOrTrailerButtons method

Comment: I added the delegate method where are linked all 4 buttons.

Comment: RajeshKumar R leave a comment to accept it. Was working your idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code inside your `if` statement will never be reached. According to Apple's documentation

> `isTouchInside` is a Boolean value indicating whether a tracked touch event is currently inside the control’s bounds.

Emphasis on the **currently**. So no two buttons will be simultaneously touched at the same time.

To achieve your goal, your buttons need some kind of state with wich you can check if the button was touched. You could simply subclass a button and add a `wasTouched` attribute, e. g.

```
class StateButton: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonWasTouched), for: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc private func buttonWasTouched() {
        self.isSelected = true
    }
}
```

Your delegate method then would look like this:

```
func tappedOnVehicleOrTrailerButtons(vehiclePassBtn: StateButton, vehicleFailBtn: StateButton, trailerPassBtn: StateButton, trailerFailBtn: StateButton) {

    if (vehiclePassBtn.isSelected || vehicleFailBtn.isSelected) && (trailerPassBtn.isSelected || trailerFailBtn.isSelected) {

        scrollDown()
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (vehiclePassBtn.isSelected || vehicleFailBtn.isSelected) && (trailerPassBtn.isSelected || trailerFailBtn.isSelected) {
            scrollDown()
}`

This way works perfectly for me.

Comment: Yes, you could also use the `isSelected` property of the button itself. I actually think that would be a better solution; I updated my answear accordingly.